# RSS Feed in Azure Permission Issue

Tags: azure, rss

Created an RSS feed with the Sitecore options. Feed works fine locally, but get the following error in the Azure site. `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`Has anyone encountered this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Is the RSS feed really just an XML file generated by the system? I wonder if you're blocking .xml (through the HttpForbiddenHandler -- https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/limit-access-to--xml,--xslt,-and--mrt-files.html ?).

Try removing that  handler from your configuration and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: I found one fix, but if it does not work it could be what you posted. I can get to xml files now though. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/582960